# How i can serialise a java object in a specific order

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I need to set this DTO object in specified order when serialising to front end.
I have tried @JsonPropertyOrder like:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"Body and Frame","Exterior Details","Interior Details",})
public class CertificateTabbings implements Serializable{

@SerializedName("Body and Frame")
private UsedcarInspectionCommonDto usedCarBodyAndFrame;

@SerializedName("Exterior Details")
private UsedcarInspectionCommonDto exteriorDetails;

@SerializedName("Interior Details")
private UsedcarInspectionCommonDto interiorDetails;
//getters //setters}
```

later i am setting the values for these object like:

```
UsedCarInspectionReport inspectionReport = new UsedCarInspectionReport();
certificateTabbing.setUsedCarBodyAndFrame(certificationDetails.getUsedCarBodyAndFrame());
certificateTabbing.setExteriorDetails(certificationDetails.getExteriorDetails());
certificateTabbing.setInteriorDetails(certificationDetails.getInteriorDetails());

inspectionReport.setCertificateTabbings(certificateTabbing);
```

using @JsonPropertyOrder didn't work for me. Any suggestion how should i get specified order in output json.

Comment: Wondering: why? Why do you have to do that? A json object, unless an array, is much more like a "map", and maps dont have an order for their elements.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes for maps no need to use ordering but as i have a loop for keys on my page i need ordering.

Comment: The front end should just treat it like a map, too. You should fix that side, not create a workaround on the other.

Answer (score 0):

@JsonPropertyOrder is part of Jackson library, whereas @SerializedName is part of GSON library. GSON doesn't support json order, so in order to make it work, change

```
@SerializedName
```

to

```
@JsonProperty
```

Note: any proper front end framework should process json without order, because http://json.org says

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

So ordering json object is probably unnecessary.

Comment: your solution is changing the order but not same as i am providing in @JsonPropertyOrder.also i am not able to see the specific names i am providing in json property

Comment: Please provide more code about specific names and response after change

Comment: In my question i have provided the code and in updated code i have just changed SerializedName to JsonProperty

Comment: Unless you provide details about "specific names that you are not able to see" it is impossible to help you. It is not clear whether or not those properties are null or empty or if this problem occured only after changing to @JsonProperty